# Mongoose - Cannot Update update deeply nested Objects

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongoose, nested

```js
var ItemSchema = new Schema({
        item: {type: String, required: false},
        ts: {type: String, required: true},
        selldate: {type: Number, required: false},
        replaced: [ReplaceSchema]
    });

    var ProductSchema = new Schema({
        title: {type: String, required: true, trim: true}, //name of the products
        artNo: {type: Number, required: true},
        catId: {type: String, required: true},
        productType: {type: String, required: true}, //physical, textbased or downloadable product | can be 'dl', 'txt', 'phy'
        tid: {type: String, required: false}, //only needed for physical products for providing a tid
        minItems: {type: Number, required: true},
        ts: {type: Number, required: true},  // when was the product online
        buyCount: {type: Number, required: true}, // baught how many times
        description: {type: String}, //more about the product
        price: {type: Number, required: true}, // how much?
        discounts: [DiscountSchema], // discount objects
        items: [ItemSchema],
        images: [], // fullsize images of the product
        thumbnails: [], // small preview images of the product
       // isPublic: {type: Boolean, required: true}, // if product should be published or not
        itemCount: {type: Number, required: false} // how many items exists on the product
    });


var CategorySchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    ts: {type: Number, required: true},
    products: [ProductSchema]
});
```

So you see its: Category -> products[] -> items[]
I want to update the Objects in items array in the database and set (at this time undefined field "selldate".

My code snippet for this looks like this:

```js
Category.getProductOfCategory(productId, function(err, boughtProduct) {
    if (err) {
        res.send({
            status: false,
            data: err
        })
    } else {
        // console.log('BoughtProduct: ', boughtProduct.products[0])
        var bought = boughtProduct.products[0];
        // console.log('theItem: ', bought.items.id(item._id));

        bought.items.id(item._id).selldate = Date.now();

        bought.save(function(err, results) {
            if (err) {
                res.send({
                    status: false,
                    data: err
                })
            } else {
                // i is increased because we need it on line 5
                //   console.log('itemerr', err)
                console.log('saved', results);
                j++;

                // the next() function is called when you
                // want to move to the next item in the array

                next();

            }
        });
    }
});
```

But nothing is happening in the database. Im getting No errors but "results" is just undefined.
Can you please help me?

**Update:**

I have a solution BUT it works only on executing it once.. after that, its nothing happening again...
The Code:

```js
Category.findById(catId, function (err, data) {
                                                        if (err) console.log(err);

                                                        data.products.id(productId).items.id(item._id).selldate = Date.now();

                                                        data.save(function (err, result) {
                                                            if (err) console.log(err);

                                                            j++;
                                                            next();
                                                        });
                                                    });
```

Comment: no one can help me?

Comment: use findById or findByAnyField method to verify if items array has the corresponding object, if an object is returned then use the object itself to update the changes.

Comment: Category.getProductOfCategor is doing this allready and its not working

Comment: I cant get it working :( its frustrating.. is there ANY way to do this update query?

Comment: i will post a solution in sometime

Comment: Thank you so much @divine!!

Comment: apologize for the delayed response. i've posted an answer.let me know if it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have posted a sample program containing documents & sub-documents.
Kindly check this and let me know if you need additional information
**Schema**

```
const PostSchema = new Schema({
        title  : String
    });

    const HomeSchema = new Schema({
        "name" : {
            type : String,
            required : true
        },
        "city" : {
            type : String,
            required : true
        },
        post : [PostSchema]
    });
```

**To Save document and subdocument**

```
    const cat = new HomeModel({
        name: "tiger",
        city : "africa",
        post : [{
            "title" : "tiger post"
        }]
    });
    cat.save((user) => {
        console.log("saved");
        console.log(user);
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
        console.log("err");
        console.log(err);
    });
```

**To update document**

```
 HomeModel.update({name : "tiger"},{city : "china123"})
        .then((home)=>{
            console.log("updated");
            console.log(home);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("error");
            console.log(error);
        });
```

**To add new subdocument**

```
HomeModel.findOne({name : "tiger"})
        .then((home) => {
            console.log("findone")
            console.log(home);
            home.post.push({"title" : "monkey"});
            home.save();
        })
        .catch((err)=>{
            console.log("error");
        });
```

**To update existing subdocument**

```
method:1
HomeModel.findOne({name : "tiger"})
        .then((home) => {
            console.log("findone")
            const tes=home.post.id("5a3fe65546c99208b8cc75b1");
            tes.set({"title" : "it workssdfg"});
            home.save();
        })
        .catch((err)=>{
            console.log("error");
        });
```

**To find parent document using sub-document id**

```
 HomeModel.findOne({"post._id" : "5a3fe65546c99208b8cc75b1"})
            .then((home) => {
                console.log("findone")
                console.log(home);
            })
            .catch((err)=>{
                console.log("error");
            });
```